# Manipulate AnimationRunning equivalent?

Tags: manipulate, animation

I have a `Manipulate` function with two variables. I would like one of them to begin autorunning immediately once the function is evaluated, but the other to remain static until moved.

Does `Manipulate` have an equivalent to `Animate`'s `AnimationRunning->True`, which would enable me to allow one of the variables to start being animated without having to convert the entire function into an `Animate`, which would affect the way the panel is displayed, as well as making both variables begin playing at once?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep Manipulate, but use Animator type for one of the sliders and control AppearanceElements to make it look whatever you need:

```
Manipulate[
 {x, y},
 {x, 0, 1, Animator, AppearanceElements -> "ProgressSlider"},
 {y, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Fantastic, @Vitaliy. Works like a treat. Thanks!